# Want to get the start and end date of a month from a particular date

Tags: java

I m having a code which gives date of a particular event like :

```
String date=date1.substring(3,5)+"/"+date1.substring(0,2)+"/"+date1.substring(6,10);
```

I want the start date and end date of the month of which the above date belongs to..

Kindly help.

Comment: So... you are looking at date or date1?  What format is date1 originally in?

Comment: you should consider using `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. You provide a `java.util.Date`, then you can get all fields. A field would be `YEAR`, `DAY` and so on.

Comment: @ bdares::     I m looking at date

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Calendar.getActualMaximum()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum%28int%29)

To get the max date of the month

```
cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

and for minimum

```
cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

**Note :** `cal` is an instance of `Calendar`

Answer (score 4):

I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for pretty much all date and time work in Java.

First I'd parse the original value into a [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html), then:

```
// Parse using DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime().toLocalDate();
LocalDate original = ...; 
LocalDate startOfMonth = original.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
LocalDate endOfMonth = original.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
```

(For the start of the month, you could just use `original.withDayOfMonth(1)` of course.)

Comment: :: String date=date1.substring(3,5)+"/"+date1.substring(0,2)+"/"+date1.substring(6,10);     gives me the date.......Plz tell me how to format it to LocalDate..

Comment: @sagarg: You need to *parse* it to a LocalDate, as I mentioned in the comment. You don't need to create a separate string - you just need to create an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter` (with the right pattern) and parse it.

Answer (score 3):

you should consider using `java.util.Calendar`. You provide a `java.util.Date`, then you can get all fields. A field would be `YEAR`, `DAY`

**EDIT (for comment)**

I'll assume that in your code snippet `date1` is a string... it also seems that you know the format (mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy), so first you need a `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // or dd/MM/yyyy
```

Then you'll need a way to parse the date... parsing a date means to convert from a string to a date object:

```
final Date date = dateFormat.parse(date1); // date1 is a date in a string in the given format
```

You have a `Date`now... All you need is to extract information from it using a `java.util.Calendar`

```
final Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.setTime(date);
```

With the `calendar`, you can get any date-related information. The first day of the month is trivial... any month starts with day number one... But for the last day of the month you need to get the maximum value for the `DAY_OF_MONTH` field:

```
int lastDayOfTheMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Anyway, I'm not making any of this stuff up... Feel free to browse the [Calendar javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and the [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It's all there, and I'm sure it is better explained than by me.